# How to reduce the height of the search view in android?

Tags: android

I have to reduce the height of the search view in android, i have set the size in the XML file but it appeared as follows

[image]

How do i reduce the size of the cursor(The search here hint is not displaying perfectly).
I want to set the size of the text in search view as the same size of 'x' button

search view XML is follows

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:text="@string/medium_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchView"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" >

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:textSize="2dp" >
        </SearchView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:onClick="hierOnclick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_list" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_add_account" />
    </LinearLayout>
....
......
........
</LinearLayout>
```

I cannot set the height as wrap_content(Please suggest some other way)

EDIT: Thanks for your comments
 I wish to create a search component as follows

[image]

to achieve this am planing to set a square background to the search view. but i cannot adjust the height of the search view.

Please help me

Thank you very much

Comment: You have specified android:layout_height="25dp"

Comment: **Post whole XML Code**

Comment: @SweetWisher yes i want the search view in a specific size

Comment: @SweetWisher i have updated my question plz have a look

Comment: Here u wrote wrap_content.. what you want now??

Comment: @SweetWisher  sorry i was  editing the code plz forgive me its my mistake i updated

Comment: So you want to fix the height or want to wrap it?

Comment: give your needed height to linear layout remove wrap_content..

Comment: Give layout: Gravity = "Center" to the SearchView

Comment: @mvnpavan i have tried but still the result is same

Comment: @ Piyush Gupta Sorry the result is same

Comment: give your search view height and width as wrap and change in linear layout fixed sizes

Comment: I didnt get what you want exactly..

Comment: @ SweetWisher  i have updated the question plz have a look

Answer (score 1):

By default `SearchView` uses `abc_search_view.xml` as it's layout file.

***abc_search_view.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    <!-- This is actually used for the badge icon *or* the badge label (or neither) -->
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/search_badge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
            android:drawablePadding="0dip"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:visibility="gone" />

   ** Omitted for brevity **
```

The root view is `R.id.search_bar`, which can be referenced and manipulated in application code to adjust height of search view:

```
searchView.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.search_bar)?.run {
    this.layoutParams = this.layoutParams.apply {
        height = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 25f, resources.displayMetrics).toInt()
    }
}
```

Then you'll probably want to center the search bar:

```
searchView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the EditText line spacing control.
you should set:

**In xml:**

```
android:lineSpacingExtra="0"
android:lineSpacingMultiplier="0"
```

**OR**

**In Code:**
Use the following method:

```
public void setLineSpacing (float add, float mult)
```

See [Android SetLineSpacing() documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float,%20float))